# Member access not legal on type LINQ error

Tags: c#, linq

I'm getting the following Error:

> Member access 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] pointsGained' of 'SuperGoalSQLDataBase.TriviaCode' not legal on type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SuperGoalSQLDataBase.TriviaCode].

Here is my code:

```
 public List<User> GetLeaderBoard()
       {
           SuperGoalDataClassesDataContext myDB = new SuperGoalDataClassesDataContext();
           var userResults = (from u in myDB.Users
                              where u.firstName != null && u.lastName != null
                              orderby (FillUserCodes(u).Sum(co => co.pointsGained ?? 0))
                             select u).Take(100);
           List<User> users = new List<User>();
           foreach (var usr in userResults)
           {
               if(usr.myPoints > 0)
                    users.Add(usr);
           }
           return users;
       }
```

Any and all help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the type of `co`?  What does `FillUserCodes()` return?

Comment: FillUserCodes returns an SQL table known as TriviaCode.
TriviaCode contains an nullable int named pointsGained.

Comment: Is `co` an instance of `TriviaCode` then?  What is the definition of `pointsGained` in the `TriviaCode` class?  Please provide relevant details.

Comment: Yes, as you can see here, co is part of a lmbda expression and is therefore an instance of TriviaCode. I do not, however, understand the second question. pointsGained is a nullable integer inside the class TriviaCode.

Comment: Instead of just describing what `pointsGained` is, can you actually *show* it?  Syntactic details are pretty important with programming languages.

Comment: I don't really understand how I can show it.
Do you mean showing an example code using it?
TriviaCode code = new TriviaCode();
code.pointsGained = 1;
Like this?

Comment: Somewhere there is a class definition for `TriviaCode`.  Within that class definition there is presumably a member definition for `pointsGained`.  The error message is telling you that you can't access `pointsGained`, so the first place to look would be that member definition to ensure that it's defined in a way that *can* be accessed.

Comment: I know for a fact it isn't private. I'm accessing it all the time from other locations. The entire TriviaCode class was auto generated in a dbml file.

Comment: Then how about `FillUserCodes()`?  Is this entire query attempting to execute as an expression tree against a data store?  Can `FillUserCodes()` be included as part of such an expression tree?  Some Google results on this error message suggest otherwise, it seems that most of the time when people see this error it's because the data context can't make sense of part of the expression.

Comment: FillUserCodes() is indeed kind of a complicated method. It calls another sql query that goes through all the TriviaCodes in MyDB.TriviaCodes and selects only those which have a userId matching the specific user I'm looking for.

Comment: Any way I can rewrite that in a way SQL will understand it?

Comment: If this is indeed an expression tree to execute against a SQL data store then I imagine you'd want to replace `FillUserCodes` with some kind of `Expression<Func<T>>` to be included as part of the LINQ to Entities expression.  Similar to something I did here: http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/06/fun-with-expression-trees.html  It might get pretty complex, depending on the implementation of `FillUserCodes`, but a series of `Expression<>`s and logical operations thereupon would be needed for the expression tree. Otherwise you'd need to materialize all the data and perform logic in-memory.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public List<User> GetLeaderBoard()
   {
       SuperGoalDataClassesDataContext myDB = new SuperGoalDataClassesDataContext();
       return myDB.Users.Where(u=> u.firstName != null && u.lastName != null).AsEnumerable()
                         .OrderBy(u=> FillUserCodes(u).Sum(co => co.pointsGained ?? 0))
                         .Take(100).Where(u=> u.mypoints > 0).ToList();
   }
```